# Xcode 4.2 decimal places

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I know this has been asked a lot of times, but I have honestly searched and I am still having problems making this work. I am not very good at coding as I am just starting to learn and teach myself. I have looked in the developer's library and all the answers on here and on Google, but I am having problems making this work. A lot of information I seem to come across is for older versions of IOS and Xcode. I need to have the number display just places after the decimal. For example, if the output is 90.909090, I need it to show 90.90 or 90.91. This works, but the output just shows 0.00, it is not reading the float. I know the output of this is just showing the  NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f" in the weightkg text filed. I am having problems referencing the float to show in this format.

```
- (IBAction)calculateweight:(id)sender {
  float wl = ([weightlbs.text floatValue]);
  float wt = (wl/2.2);

  weightkg.text =  [[NSNumber numberWithFloat:wt] stringValue]; 
 [weightkg setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f"]];

}
```

Comment: You might want to learn the difference between "Xcode" and "Objective-C"...

Comment: This functionality is basically lifted straight out of C.  You can read about format strings by running `man 3 printf` from the command line; the same format (with a couple additions) is used for `stringWithFormat:`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not passing the float value to stringWithFormat, try this.

```
- (IBAction)calculateweight:(id)sender {
  float wl = ([weightlbs.text floatValue]);
  float wt = (wl/2.2);

 [weightkg setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", wt]];

}
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked exactly like I needed it to. I had tried something like this before, but I was still trying to use NSNumber numberWithFloat instead of using the NSString stringWithFormat and getting errors.

Answer (score 4):

You should be using:

```
float wt = ...;
weightkg.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f", wt];
```

That is, you must pass the variable value to your `stringWithFormat` call.